# Age verification doesn't get full year in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, validation, country

I have a dropdown for countries:

```
<select id="country" name="country" aria-disabled="false">
        <option value="AU" age="18" selected="selected">Australia</option>
        <option value="US" age="21">United States</option>
        <option value="UK" age="18">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="HK" age="19">Canada</option>
</select>
```

and 3 selects for Days, Months and Year
For some reason, the age gate counts only the year, but it doesn't count days and months. So when the person has a birthday at the end of the year, the form submits successfully instead of pushing the Age notification. Can't get what I'm doing wrong :
This is my code below:

```
        var t = function (t, e) {
            return e.getFullYear() - t.getFullYear();
        };
        $.get("https://ipapi.co/country/", function (t) {
            (clientCountry = "AU"), (clientCountry = t);
            $("#country option[value=" + clientCountry + "]").val();
            $("#country option[value=" + clientCountry + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
            var e = $("#country option:selected").attr("age");
            $("#age-gate__country .ui-selectmenu-status").text($("select[name=country] option:selected").text());
            var age = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - e)).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
            $("#targetAge").text(age),
                "US" === clientCountry || "UK" === clientCountry
                    ? ($(".age-gate__content__options").addClass("visible"), $(".age-gate__content__options").removeClass("visible"))
                    : ($(".age-gate__content__options").removeClass("visible"), $(".age-gate__content__options").addClass("visible"));
        }),
            $("#ageGateAdvancedForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var age = $("#country option:selected").attr("age"),
                    date = $("#v65-billBirthDay option:selected").val(),
                    month = $("#v65-billBirthMonth option:selected").val(),
                    year = $("#v65-billBirthYear option:selected").val(),
                    today = new Date(),
                    // s = new Date(),
                    birth = new Date(year, month, date),
                    c = t(birth, today);
                c >= age && c < 100 ? ($(".age-gate").removeClass("age-gate__active"), vtScripts.cookies("ageGate", "remember", 365)) : $("#agegate-error").text("You must be older than " + age + "!");
            });
```

UPDATE:
This is how I edited the code below

```
$("#ageGateAdvancedForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var a = $("#country option:selected").attr("age"),
                    i = $("#v65-billBirthDay option:selected").val(),
                    n = $("#v65-billBirthMonth option:selected").val(),
                    o = $("#v65-billBirthYear option:selected").val(),
                    s = new Date(),
                    r = new Date(o, n - 1, i),
                    c = t(r, s);

                    const dt = new Date();
                    dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() - a);
                    c = dt.getTime() - new Date(r).getTime();
                    c >= a ? ($(".age-gate").removeClass("age-gate__active"), vtScripts.cookies("ageGate", "remember", 365)) : $("#agegate-error").text("You must be older than " + a + "!");
     
            });
```

Comment: You're ignoring the actual dates and looking at just the year: `return e.getFullYear() - t.getFullYear();`

Comment: You should add an integer to birth year and Check with current date.

Comment: You are checking the full year. you need to verify the month and day is before or after.

Comment: Would simplify your code if you used an [input type=date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

Comment: @Yogi yes, I agree, but I need separate fields, so playing with this

Answer (score 0):

Solutiuon:

```
$("#ageGateAdvancedForm").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $("#country option:selected").attr("age"),
    i = $("#v65-billBirthDay option:selected").val(),
    n = $("#v65-billBirthMonth option:selected").val(),
    o = $("#v65-billBirthYear option:selected").val(),
    s = new Date(),
    r = new Date(o, n - 1, i),
    c = t(r, s);

  const dt = new Date();
  dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() - a);
  c = dt.getTime() - new Date(r).getTime();
  c >= a ?
    ($(".age-gate").removeClass("age-gate__active"), vtScripts.cookies("ageGate", "remember", 365))
    : $("#agegate-error").text("You must be older than " + a + "!");
});
```